# Pods: Xcode's Library Search Paths not getting updated for one target after running pod install, but it is for all other targets

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an app with 5 extensions, and I'm adding pods to all 6 targets.

I had linking issues with one of the extensions and I discovered the Library Search Path section for its target was different from all the other targets, and this was the cause of the build issue. After manually updating it to match the other targets, it built, linked, and ran.

My question is - as this section gets updated automatically by the pod file/command, why is it not getting updated for one target but it is for all the others? The pod spec is the same. I tried running pod deintegrate and then pod install again, but it makes no difference.
I want to know why the Xcode build section isn't getting set for this specific target.

Here's a section of the pod file, showing the extension in question (the CallExtension), and a couple of other extensions too.

```
workspace 'CeqProject'
<snip>
target 'CallExtension' do 
   project 'CeqProject.xcodeproj'
   pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
end


target 'UnwantedCommunicationExtension' do
    project 'CeqProject.xcodeproj'
    pod 'PhoneNumberKit'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
end

target 'NotificationContentExtension' do
    project 'CeqProject.xcodeproj'
    pod 'PhoneNumberKit'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
end
<snip>
```

After running pod install, within Xcode the Library Search Path for the Call Extension is like this:
[image]

However, for all the other targets, its like this:
[image]

Why is pod install not setting/updating the Call Extension target's Library Search Paths but it is for all the other targets?